# nodejs uploading pdf to S3 bucket corrupt file

Tags: node.js, pdf, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am currently using aws-sdk to upload pdf files to bucket S3, like this:

```
function uploadFile (filePath, remoteFilename, cb) {
    var fileBuffer = fs.createReadStream(filePath); // ex.: 'temp/longFileName.pdf'
    fileBuffer.on('error', function(err) {
        logger.warn('Failed reading local pdf file');
        cb(err);
    });
    s3.upload({
        Bucket: 'someBucketName',
        Key: remoteFilename,
        Body: fileBuffer
    }, function (error, response) {
        cb(error, { response, remoteFilename });
    });
}
```

the problem is that sometimes the file gets uploaded with 0B size, sometimes it gets uploaded with the correct size, but when I download it, it is corrupt, and of course sometimes it is correctly uploaded and opens properly.

I read the pdf file locally from system file, and that pdf file is correct.

could somebody help me to fix this issue?

### update

I am creating a pdf using [pdfkit](https://github.com/devongovett/pdfkit):

```
function createPdf (data, cb) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    var PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
    var filePath = 'temp/longFileName.pdf';
    var pdf = new PDFDocument({
      size: 'LEGAL',
      info: {
        Title: 'Tile of File Here',
        Author: 'Some Author',
      }
    });

    // Write stuff into PDF
    pdf.text('Hello World');

    // Stream contents to a file
    pdf.pipe(
      fs.createWriteStream(filePath)
    )
      .on('finish', function () {
        console.log('PDF closed');
      });

    // Close PDF and write file.
    pdf.end();
    cb(null, {filePath})
}
```

once the callback in this function is called, i call the `uploadFile` function:

```
function doAll (someData, cb) {

    createPdf(someData, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err)

        uploadFile(data.filePath, function(err,data) {
            if (err) console.log(err)
            console.log('finished')
            cb(null, 'done');
            return;
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Since the file is in `temp/`, I assume that file was just saved, Are you sure it was fully written before you try to open it?, can we see where do you call `uploadFile`?

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande i updated the question with the other functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling the callback immediately instead of waiting for the file to be fully written. Your callback function should be inside `.on('finish')`

```
pdf.pipe(
  fs.createWriteStream('./path/to/file.pdf')
)
.on('finish', function () {
    console.log('PDF closed');
    cb(null, 'finished'); // The callback should e in here
});

// Close PDF and write file.
pdf.end();
```

Comment: i see, how about the `s3.upload` function? should it be inside the `fileBuffer.on` too?

Comment: No no, `s3.uploader` takes a stream, so it shouldn't be inside any listener. Just pass the stream to it.

Comment: i mean, should i also wait until the file has a readable stream too? cuz i am opening it in uploadFile function, and then uploading it to S3... should i wait until it is fullly readable?

Comment: As soon as you call `fs.createReadStream` you have a valid readableStream, you don't have to wait, just pass it to `s3.uploader`, `s3` knows how to work with streams, and it will handle it correctly.